# How to edit only one row at a time in ag grid? Angular7

Tags: angular7, ag-grid

I want to edit only one row at a time and stop the user from editing other rows until the first row is closed or any editable row for that matter is closed.

Right now I have an edit button which is developed on a custom component. Setting flag to restrict is not working as well.

the custom button component:

```
  template: `
<button type="button" *ngIf="isNew == true" style="width:50px;" (click) = "onEditClick()" (onchange)="onChangeTest()" data-action-type="view" class="btn btn-iconsize1 btn-link lni-pencil-alt">
</button>
<button type="button"  *ngIf="isNew == false" (click) = "onUpdateClick()" data-action-type="view" class="fa fa-check-circle text-success iconsize3">
</button>
<button type="button" *ngIf="isNew == false" (click) = "onCancelClick()" data-action-type="view" class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger iconsize3">
</button>`,

   onEditClick() {
    console.log(this.params);
    this.params.data['isEdited'] = true;
    // storing old data for comparison
    this.editParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.params.data));
    this.isNew = !this.isNew;
    if (this.setFlag === true) {
       alert('close');
    } else {
      this.params.api.startEditingCell({
        rowIndex: this.params.node.rowIndex,
        colKey: 'mtmFlag'
        });
    }
    this.setFlag = true;        
    // else {
    //   alert('already on edit');
    // }
}
```

Main component from where the button component is called:

```
constructor(private DataService: ResourceService, private UnderscoreService: UnderscoreServices) {
    this.columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Edit',
            field: 'action',
            sortable: true,
            filter: false,
            cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',  // this is the button component
            cellRendererParams: {
                cancelOtherRowEditors: this.cancelOtherRowEditors.bind(this),
            },
            width: 100,
            pinned: 'left'
        },
```

}

Let me know if I can freeze or give a prompt to restrict multiple row edit.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a Plunker or StackBlitz please.

Comment: Check out https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/